# No sound from headphones on Samsung Series 7 Chronos ( NP700Z5a )

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I know it's an old question, but I've gone through the FAQs on Ubuntu.com and can't find the solution.

Speakers work fine - ie if I go to System Settings > Sound, the tests sound. As soon as I plug in my headphones, it goes dead.

Some diagnostics:

```
duncan@pliny:~$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c0b3
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at c0800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

And also

```
duncan@pliny:~$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
Home directory /home/duncan not ours.
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And my alsamixer:

Headphones plugged in:
[image: With headphones plugged in]

Headphones unplugged:
[image: With headphones unplugged]

Thanks

**Edit**

It seems there is sound from headphones - it's just unbelieveably faint...

Answer (score 3):

Installing the [ALSA/DKMS package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS) for Intel sound cards fixed this